# Change icon in applications menu - Symbian Qt (QML)

Tags: qt, menu, icons, qml, symbian

What I am trying to do is to change my application's icon in the menu at runtime. For example, when the user taps a button, my application's icon in the menu should change to another SVG already stored in the project.
So, does anyone know how to achieve this?
I am using Qt Creator on Windows 8 64-bit to develop a Symbian Qt Quick application (for Qt 4.7).

Or, if this is not possible, then please help my with a snippet of code for Symbian C++ which would change either my application's  icon in menu, either another's applications icon in menu to another one I specify.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't think it will work. I have noticed that when I change the icon of my application and reinstall it then the old icon is still shown until I reboot my phone.